# The images are not keeping the sequence

Tags: formatting

This should be a common issue on this site, but I did not find the information I needed.

Why did not my images follow the sequence I tried to define?

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PARTE 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Parte 1}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Capítulo 1
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Seções
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Introdução}
Quando você abre o aplicativo SOLIDWORKS pela primeira vez, a tela que você vê é a seguinte:

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14cm]{1.png}
    \caption{Tela inicial}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\section{Interface do Usuário}
Abra no botão Novo:

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14cm]{2.png}
    \caption{Botão novo}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\section{Comandos da Interface do usuário}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Barra de menus
    \item Barras de ferramentas
    \item Gerenciador de comandos (CommandManager)
    \item Gerenciador de configurações
    \item Gerenciador de propriedades
    \item Filtro da árvore de projeto
    \item Trilhas de seleção
    \item Árvore de projeto do FeatureManager
    \item Barra de status
    \item Barra de ferramentas transparente
    \item Painel de tarefas
    \item Área de gráficos
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**1.png**

[image: 1]

**2.png**

[image: 2]

Comment: It's one of the most common "issues"... (for those who didn't realize it's a feature)

Comment: I already imagined. Sorry for my ignorance on the subject, but I'm happy for the cordiality of everyone here on this site.